# Convert Apache .htaccess rules to IIS web.config to append .php file extensions

Tags: .htaccess, iis, web-config, plesk

I am using below `.htaccess` code. But I need to convert my `.htaccess` file content to `web.config` file. I have no idea how to do it. please check my `.htaccess` code below:

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

How can I convert this to `web.config`?

Comment: found the answer

Answer (score 2):

we can put below content to the web.config file

```
    ﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation tempDirectory="D:\WWW\ovintours.com\tmp" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```